# Static-looking model upon importing to blender from rhino

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, import

I'm trying to import from Rhino to Blender but I always seem to get this same issue  where the model looks blotchy. I'm relatively new to blender so I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this. I'm wondering if it's an issue on blender's end or if the something going wrong when exporting in rhino.
[image: splotchy artifacts on model]

[image: rendered model]

When rendered and lit by a sun lamp, the black spots can be seen still. I honestly have no idea what's going wrong. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Edit: I have been using obj. file format to import

[image: model in 3d viewer]

There are extra surfaces when viewed in 3d viewer

Comment: What file format are you using ? I would recommand obj. You can try removing doubles (select all, W, remove doubles) and recalculate normals (select all, Ctrl+N)

Comment: You could try to open your exported file with another viewer (like https://3dviewer.net/), to see if the issue is Blender or Rhino side

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have been exporting as an obj. I tried what you said and the model has some weird extra surfaces that weren't present in the rhino file.  Does this suggest a problem with the export?

Comment: As far as I know, Rhino mostly works withs NURBS instead of polygons. Maybe the exporter do a bad job when converting to polygons ? I you can, try doing the conversion manually in Rhino before exporting, use triangles (its usually safer than Ngons), try exporting in .stl... Maybe ask the question on a Rhino website ?